# Issues with python operators

Tags: python, operators, range

Im working on a for where the user enters their weight and it is displayed later in the program. Their weight has to be between 0 and 500, for some reason I can't seem to get the program to accept any weight in the correct range.

```
weight = raw_input("Enter your Weight: ")

while not weight.isdigit() or weight >500 or weight<=0:

    if not weight.isdigit():
        print "Invalid Number. Try Again."
        weight = raw_input("Enter your Weight: ")

    if weight > 500:
        print "Invalid Number. Try Again."
        weight = raw_input("Enter your Weight: ")

    if weight < 1:
        print "Invalid Number. Try Again."
        weight = raw_input("Enter your Weight: ")
```

I've also tried using range(0, 500) but nothing seems to be working. I'm sure its a simple solution and I feel like an idiot not being able to get it.

Comment: Raw input returns a string. You must convert it to an int. like this `int(raw_input("Enter your Weight: ")`

Comment: Don't compare int with a string: `int(raw_input("Enter your Weight: "))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert your input as an integer before comparing it to 0 and 500.
Here is an updated version of your code, which tries to cast the input as an integer and break the infinite loop only if the weight is between 0 and 500 (exclusive).

```
while True:
    try:
        weight = int(raw_input("Enter your Weight: "))
    except ValueError:
        print "Please enter a valid number. Try Again."
    else:
        if 0 < weight < 500:
            break

        print "Invalid Number (should be between 0 and 500). Try Again."
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable 'weight' is a str, and you're running into cross-type comparison issues.  For, say, 300, weight > 500 evaluates to True.  If you cast it to an integer before the '>' it should work, i.e. change

```
weight > 500
```

to

```
int(weight) > 500
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to an integer first.

```
weight = int(raw_input("Enter your Weight: "))

while not weight.isdigit() or weight >500 or weight<=0:

    if not weight.isdigit():
        print "Invalid Number. Try Again."

    if weight > 500:
        print "Invalid Number. Try Again."

    if weight < 1:
        print "Invalid Number. Try Again."

    weight = int(raw_input("Enter your Weight: "))
```